Adding a column and resize table with fitDataStretch layout
When I add a column to a table with fitDataStretch set, the column is appended to the table but the previous column is not resized. That way, the added column makes the table wider than the screen, and the user must scroll to reach the added column.
Is there a way to recalculate the column widths so the table fits the width of the screen again? I tried with table.redraw() but no luck.
https://jsfiddle.net/0tf1xzrv/3/
Right click the last column and add a column to see what I mean. I'm using tabulator 6.2.1.
